# execute operators from a variable

Tags: php, arrays, operators, eval

I am trying to execute operators from a variable/array.

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => +
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => +
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => +
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => -
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => +
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => *
                    [4] => 4
                )
```

The total operators and integers within the array is dynamic. I can have 7 integers with 6 operators. It is always in the format `[int + op + int + op +int ....]`

I was thinking to use `eval()`. I know that eval is evil and it is not recommended to use, but I don't use it in public.

I am stuck with this peace of code:

```
function getResults($array) {

    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $subarray) {
        $eval = '';
        $result[$key] = array();


        foreach($subarray as $subsubarray) {
            $exec = '';
            foreach($subsubarray as $data) {
                $exec .=  ' ' . $data;
            }

            ltrim($exec ,' ');

            $result = eval("?>$exec");
            echo $result;
        }

    }
}
```

When I execute this I get this:

```
6 + 2 + 4
6 + 2 - 4
6 + 2 * 4
6 + 2 / 4
6 - 2 + 4
6 - 2 - 4
6 - 2 * 4
6 - 2 / 4
....
```

I am expecting to get the result like :

```
 8
 4
 14
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's fine apart from the way you're calling `eval()`:

```
$result = eval('return ' . $exec . ';');
```

I'm sure I don't need to point out that unsanitised user input shouldn't be going anywhere near that function...

Comment: Thank you, its working now. I know that eval is danger when you don't use it the right way.